# No HttpMessageConverter for [com.example.blog.SnapEngChatRequest] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, resttemplate

I wanted to call a post API with form URL encoded header. Here's my code

```
 var data = SnapEngChatRequest(
            widgetId = widgetId,
            visitorMessage = "Test"
    )

    val headers = HttpHeaders()

    headers.set("x-api-key", apiKey)
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    val entity = HttpEntity(data, headers)

    val converter = FormHttpMessageConverter()
    converter.supportedMediaTypes = singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    restTemplate.messageConverters.add(converter)

    val result = restTemplate.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            entity,
            String::class.java
    )
```

But unfortunately, it is not working and I'm getting below error

```
No HttpMessageConverter for [com.example.blog.SnapEngChatRequest] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for [com.example.blog.SnapEngChatRequest] and content type [application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
```

Here, I'm giving the httpMessageConverter but I'm not sure why it is not taking or I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here. I have tried everything possible. Any help will be helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From documentation for [FormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedMultiValueMap.html) it can:

> ... read and write the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" media type
>   as MultiValueMap

So it can't read it from a POJO. Send your data like this:

```
val data = LinkedMultiValueMap(
  mapOf("widgetId" to listOf(widgetId), "visitorMessage" to listOf("Test"))
)
```

Comment: Yaa Thanks. I know this way and it is working but is it possible to with the message converters that I did in my code?

Comment: I referred this link [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest)

Comment: There is no generic converters in Spring to serialize POJOs to form data, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please check the above link in the comment?

Comment: It's not possible with built-in converters. You would have to write your own. But why? You can for example write a helper method in your POJOs `toMap` that will serialize your object to a `LinkedMultiValueMap` that you can send with RestTemplate.

Comment: Thanks! 
Actually, with the LinkedMultiValueMap, I have to pass every parameter(suppose if there are 20 or more variables then it is not feasible so) and If in future the parameter will be changed then I have to again change this function so just wanted some generic converters that will convert it automatically.

Comment: Would be better if the other side just accepted JSON.

Comment: Yeah true, but I'm consuming an API that requires application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Btw Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using spring boot here and I too get the same error what OP got here, the accepted solution didn't work out to me. At least tell me some ways so I can overcome this problem.

I tried the curl with `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it successfully gave me the response but the same when I try with sping boot I'm getting the error `[ERROR] Exception while sending sms : No HttpMessageConverter for <<My_Class_Name>> and content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`