# RestTemplate exception no converters found while testing a Spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am new to testing world of spring boot application.
I want to do an integration testing on my Spring boot application. But i am getting following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null
```

I am adding an employee and department into the in-memory database with bi-directional relationship.

```
public void testPostEmployee() throws Exception
            {       
        System.out.println("Inside Post Employee method");

        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        EmployeeTestDTO employeeTestDTO = new EmployeeTestDTO();
        DepartmentTest departmentTest = new DepartmentTest(1,"Sales");
        employeeTestDTO.setName("ABC");
        employeeTestDTO.setAge(20);
        employeeTestDTO.setSalary(1200.1);
        employeeTestDTO.setDepartmentTest(departmentTest);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String data = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employeeTestDTO);
        System.out.println(data);

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(data,httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<?> postResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(createURLWithPort("/employee"), 
                httpEntity,String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(201, postResponse.getStatusCodeValue());            

}
```

This is my new edit. As per previously stated suggestion i tried to implement all of them but neither of them succeded. It gives the bad request 400 null exception. Please suggest me how to solve it

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, autowire your `RestTemplate` instance instead of using `new`; you'll get one that has auto-configured converters and such.

Comment: Still it shows the same exception..!

Comment: may be see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812574/no-httpmessageconverter-for-com-example-blog-snapengchatrequest-and-content-ty

Comment: I watched it. But didn't solve either. I have updated the code. Please have a look

Comment: change header to `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` and try @VanditShah that should work

Comment: Tried that also.  Showing org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null
 at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)

Comment: You cannot directly assign your `employeeTestDTO` to `HttpEntity` with `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` in headers. You should transform it to JSON string as request body.

Comment: Please view my new edit

Comment: Please add the controller you are trying to test to your question.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should change ContentType from  `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` to `APPLICATION_JSON`.

```
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Also you need to add RestController:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/employee")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void getEmploee(@RequestBody EmployeeTestDTO employee) {
        System.out.println(employee);
    }
}
```